# Visual Studio: How to get the selected filename from the project tree for usage in a powershell script?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015

I **need to use** the name of the **selected element in my file explorer** (solution explorer) in my powershell script.

There is a project in my project tree under which are several subdirectories.
I configured a custom external tool (powershell script) whose configuration allows me to right-click on one of those subdirectoreis of my project and execute my powershell script.
Now, the thing is '**where do i get the selected directory name from?**'.

I already had a look into the available [arguments for external tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekbzk5f8(v=vs.71).aspx) and tried to use them but none of them gave me what i want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem myself.
I had to use the parameter `$(ItemPath)` as an additional argument to the external powerscript tool. The description to the parameter `ItemPath` is a bit misguiding but it gives me what i want.